# connection lost to glustferfs when amazon ec2 internal ip address changes

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, glusterfs

My web site running on EC2 instances. Web servers stores dynamic data in glusterfs servers. When the glusterfs instances are restarted, their ip addresses changes, so that web servers lost the connection to glusterfs.

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior of EC2.  If you want more granular control over your IP addressing, you're going to have to create instances inside of a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).

Comment: Yep. Anyone running a cluster rather than individual isolated instances should be using a VPC for the control it offers.

Comment: @ceeyayoz, Should I add my web servers to VPC too? If so, my web servers are controlled by a autoscaling group. Is it possible to create a autoscaling group in VPC? If I needn't to add web servers to VPC how could my web servers reach the gluster servers?

Comment: @zontragon Yes, autoscaling is possible within VPC. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/autoscalingsubnets.html Your web servers should be in a public VPC subnet, with routing and security groups allowing them to contact Gluster instances in a private subnet.